# Atom git-diff is not working in mac machine

Tags: atom-editor, git-diff

I am using Atom in Mac. Whenever I press `alt+g up/down` it just inserts © symbol rather than showing the next diff. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you press "alt-g" and then "up" or "down"? Try activating the [keybinding resolver](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) "cmd-." to see what your keystrokes resolve to

Comment: Alt+G with up or down did not change anything.

Comment: @Neo did you ever figure out how to get this running on a Mac?

Comment: @PierreSpring I moved to VSCode :D

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> on a Mac inserts the `©` symbol.

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> in Atom on a Mac delays the insertion of the `©` symbol for a second. If you hit the <kbd>▲</kbd> or <kbd>▼</kbd> key during that time, the insertion of the `©` symbol is prevented, and the cursor jumps to the previous or next diff in your file.

It's all just a matter of timing.